# C - SizeOf Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, character, sizeof

```
char c[] = {'a','b','c'};
int* p = &c[0];
printf("%i\n", sizeof(*p)); //Prints out 4
printf("%i\n", sizeof(*c)); //Prints out 1
```

I am extremely confused about this section of code. Both p and c represent the address of the array c at the 0th index. But why does sizeof(*p) print out 4? Shouldn't it be 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `p` is of type `int *`, so `*p` is of type `int`, which is apparently 4 bytes wide on your implementation.

---

And use `%zu` for printing `size_t` (what `sizeof` yields) if you don't want your program to invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Or convert to `int` and use `"%d"` or `"%i"` if your implementation (*cough*Microsoft*cough*) doesn't support `"%zu"`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yup :) (MS would seriously need to start living in the XXIth century and support at least C99...)

Comment: Or, better, convert to `unsigned long` and use `"%lu"`

Comment: @KeithThompson why does `int p` pointer accept address of `char` .this code `int* p = &c[0]`. i though only `void*` pointers could take any type

Comment: @CholthiPaulTtiopic: It doesn't. Given `char c[10]`, gcc warns `initialization from incompatible pointer type`

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof(*p)` is the size of the `int` object to which `p` points.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof(*p) will print size of p which is 4 because of int but c is of char that's why it is 1

Answer (score 0):

In C (not C99) the `sizeof` operator is strictly a compile time calculation.  so when `sizeof (*p)` [a dereferenced ptr to an integer] is evaluated then the size of `int` is four.

Note. the `(*p)` portion of that statement is a "cast" operator.  So, sizeof is NOT a function call as in `sizeof(xyz)`, rather it is like `sizeof var_name` or `sizeof (int *)`.

When your program runs it changes the object pointed to by p, but the value of `sizeof (*p)` was already computed and hard-coded into your executable load module.

I think your confusion is that you were thinking that C would figure out what data type p was pointing to when your program runs.