# pass array pointer as a parameter

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to pass an int array as a pointer to a function. I'm currently getting the following error: `expected 'int (*)[100]' but argument is of type 'int *' void.`

```
void count_frequency(int *number) {
    int i;
    int len = sizeof number / sizeof(int);
    printf("%i\n", len);
    printf("reached here");
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
        printf("%i\n", &number[i]);
    }
}



int main(){
    int i;
    int table[MAX];
    int len = sizeof table / sizeof(int);
    printf("reached before loop\n");

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
        table[i] = random_in_range(0, 20); 
    }
    count_frequency(table);

    //printf("%i", sizeof(table) / sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int len = sizeof number / sizeof(int);` manually check what this returns on different sized arrays.

Comment: What returns random_in_range function?

Comment: Read [Weird behavior when printing array in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009725/weird-behavior-when-printing-array-in-c/18009736#18009736)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C - SizeOf Pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363037/c-sizeof-pointers)

Comment: random_in_range returns a random number between 0 - 20

Comment: 1. Get rid of `int len = sizeof number / sizeof(int);`, which is very wrong. 2. The compilation error you're reporting is not within the code you provide; possibly in function `random_in_range`? or in the way you've defined `MAX`?

Comment: @EdS. it's about a compile error...

Comment: strange message. and  `printf("%i\n", &number[i]);` : remove `&`.

Comment: @mb84: True... though that error makes no sense given his code sample.

Comment: @mb84: But the error message states that it is *expecting* a pointer to an array, yet he is *passing* an `int*`.  Those would be reversed if you were correct.  The only type mismatch I see is in the `printf` call.

Comment: @EdS. oh, yes, my bad. Then maybe some double usage of `number` (typedef, macro, ...)?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is inconsistent with the error you're getting. The only wrong things are:

- Remember that %d or %i require an integer passed as argument
- I assume the "random_in_range" function uses the rand() as follows

  ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   #define MAX 100


   int random_in_range(int a, int b)//this function will generate a random number between specified range
   {
       return (a+rand()%(b-a+1));
   }


   void count_frequency(int *number) {
        int i;
        int len = sizeof number / sizeof(int);
        printf("%i\n", len);
        printf("reached here");
        for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
         printf("%d\n", number[i]);
         }
   }



   int main(){
        int i;
        int table[MAX];
        int len = sizeof table / sizeof(int);
        printf("reached before loop\n");

        for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
              table[i] = random_in_range(0, 20); 
        }
        count_frequency(table);

        printf("%i", sizeof(table) / sizeof(int));
        return 0;
   }
  ```

http://ideone.com/LG96iA

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, "sizeof number" is going to return the size of the pointer (4 bytes) rather than the size of the array.