# Using sizeof with char *array[]

Tags: c, arrays

I am new to programming. Now I am learning `C` and `Java`.

I have an array like this -

```
char *array = {"zero", "one", "two", "three"};
```

From this `link` I can print the array content like this -

```
printf("%s %s", array[0], array[1]); //zero one
```

But my question is how can I print the length of referenced by `array[0]`, `array[1]` and so on. I know I can do some thing like this -

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof("zero");
```

But can I print the size using `array` variable itself.

I have tried with different ways like -

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof(array[0]);  //4
printf("%d\n", sizeof(*array[0]);  //1
```

But each time I get wrong answer.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [C - SizeOf Pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363037/c-sizeof-pointers)

Comment: By the way, the declaration `char *array = {};` does not declare an array of `char` pointers, or in this case strings, it should be `char *array[] = {"zero",  ... }`.

Comment: I am not looking for the sizeof pointer. I am looking for the string length refrenced by the pointer. Probably I have made a mess between size and length. Thats why the confusion occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen).

```
printf("%d\n", (int) strlen(array[0]));
```

Comment: why the down vote.  This IS the correct answer for the question the OP ask

Comment: @user3629249 `array[0]` has type `char`!

Comment: Oh! thanks I am looking for this. Probably my question was confusing. But you understand my requirements.

Answer (score 4):

The size of each element of the array is the same because the array is declared as an array of pointers

```
char * array[] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three"};  
^^^^^^
```

(Notice you have to use record array[] )

That is each element of the array has type `char *` and correspondingly its size is equal to 4 in the environment where you run the program.

Actually you want to get sizes of string literals that are pointed to by the elements of the array. To do this you can use standard C function `strlen` declared in header `<string.h>` The function will return the number of characters in a string literal up to the terminating zero character.

```
printf( "%zu\n", strlen( array[0] ) ); // returns 4 for "zero"
printf( "%zu\n", strlen( array[1] ) ); // returns 3 for "one"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, if you want to declare an array of `char *` i.e. `char` pointers, to string literals, two things are missing, `[]` and `const`, because you don't want to accidentally modify that, so

   ```
   const char *array[] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three"};
   ```

   would be the correct way.
2. The reason is the `nul` terminator, in

   ```
   printf("%zu\n", sizeof(array[0]))
   ```

   the correct value is `5` and not `4` because `"zero"` uses `5` bytes `"zero\0"` instead of `4`, the last one is a `nul` terminator that marks the end of a c string.

   If your strings are very simple and regular, then `sizeof(array[0]) - 1` will give the correct value, although it's not a robust solution, because it assumes that the string is a simple string like `"zero"`, it will fail if the string has embeded `'\0'` bytes, like `"zero\0one\0"` which is a valid string literal and for which `sizeof` will give `10`.

   The correct way of getting the length of a string in c, is by iterating through the bytes until the `'\0'` appears, which is what [`strlen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html) does, so you can use `strlen()` very carefuly, because it might fail very easily if you're not careful, and also

   ```
   printf("%zu\n", strlen("zero\0one\0"));
   ```

   will return `4`, because the first occurrance of the `'\0'` will suffice for the function to return.

   Also `printf("%s\n", "zero\0one\0");` would output `zero`, because of the same reason.

   The most dangerous thing of `strlen()` would be to pass a non `nul` terminated sequence, which would cause undefined behavior, with string literals there is no danger at all, but if you define an array and manually fill the characters, it's really easy to forget to add the terminating `'\0'`, and it's not that hard to use `strlen()`.

Comment: `sizeof(array[0])` is `sizeof(char*)` and has no relation to the string contents.

Comment: Ooops, I didn't see the variable was declared as `char *`.